# UNIX_TIMESTAMP getting null

Tags: mysql

This is getting NULL, why?

```
select unix_timestamp(addtime(date(now()), time(from_unixtime(1426705199))))
```

For some reason, it is running correctly, however it only outputs NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often find, when confronted with an error, that the manual can be a useful resource:

`ADDTIME() adds expr2 to expr1 and returns the result. expr1 is a time or datetime expression, and expr2 is a time expression.`

You are using a date value for expr1. Try casting it back to datetime expression:

```
select unix_timestamp(addtime(
   timestamp(date(now()))
   , time(from_unixtime(1426705199))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work?

```
 SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

If you want to get it from your own field then use this..

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourField);
```

Comment: I want to generate hour:min from other field

Comment: @symcbean Give me answer, anyway Thanks guys!